# Нарисовать интерактивный график с 1e+7 точек

Tags: big-data

Всем привет!
Стоит задача получить с устройства 1e+7 точек и отобразить их на графике. Собственно, с отображением на графике и возникли проблемы.
Пытался реализовать на `Qt`, с помощью `QCustomPlot`, однако, столкнулся с проблемой переполнения оперативной памяти.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой инструментарий использовать (язык, библиотеки) для такого рода задач?
Что можно почитать?

Comment: Думаю Вам необходимо усечь точки (увеличить дескретность). т.е. брать не все а каждую сотую, например.

Comment: Но если очень сильно хочется все же отрисовать такое кол-во точек - рисуйте ручками на картинке в памяти. Она стерпит.

Comment: @KoVadim нужна интерактивность. Вопрос поправил, спасибо

Comment: А что в Вашем случае "интерактивность"? возможность позуммить? показать тултипы?

Comment: @KoVadim зум, возможность выбрать точку

Comment: мой ответ в этом случае тот же. При зуме просто пересчитывается картинка. Выбор точки - это ещё одна "дорисовка повер готовой картинки".

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, а нет ли готовых библиотек?